# How to import com.android.support:design:23.0.1 in eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am learning the android tab with swipe functionality using material theme. I have a sample tutorials from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) and it is build from Android studio.

I am currently using eclipse for my project.

I am following the tutorial and i can't import the `TabLayout` from `com.android.support:design`

Below is the code,

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

Showing the error, `The import android.support.design cannot be resolved`

I downloaded `support:design:23.0.1` from [here](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design) and imported to eclipse, even then the error appears.

Can any one tell me where to download and import the  `com.android.support:design:23.0.1` in eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: Import the library project from sdk\extras\android\support\design the same way as you would import appcompat-v7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install `Android SDK 23.0.1`
2. Import `design` library from `sdk\extras\android\support\design` into eclipse workspace
3. To mark the `design` project as Library, open properties -> Select Android ->Check `Library`
4. Now import this `design` Library to your Project from project properties.

This worked for me in Tab material design.

If the `design` folder is not found in the said location, try to locate it in `sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design` instead, especially for the later version.

Answer (score 2):

I have also face same problem then find solution like this.

It work for me hope same for You.

**First Step:-** find .aar file for **design-23.0.1.aar**

```
E:\new sdk\sdk\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design\23.0.1
```

**Second Step:-** copy that file and rename it like `design-23.0.1.jar` to be extract this.
After unzip it you find classes.jar, res, AndroidManifest etc.

**Third Step:-** Create Library project in eclipse Named ***design*** and copy

- `classes.jar` in libs folder
- all res in res/
- replace AndroidManifest.xml
  and last add lib `appcompat-v7` by right click on `lib project -> properties-> Android -> add -> appcompat-v7`

Most important do not forgot clean project and can be restart eclipse for refreshing eclipse.

And more deep details follow steps **Guided by** [***commonsware's blog***](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html)

- Create an empty directory that will be the home for the Android
  library project. For the rest of these steps, I will refer to this as
  “the output directory”.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, **res/**, and **assets/** directories from the
  AAR into the output directory.
- Create a libs/ directory in the output directory. Copy into libs/ the
  `classes.jar` from the root of the unZIPped AAR, plus anything in libs/
  in the AAR (e.g., mediarouter-v7 has its own JAR of proprietary
  bits).
- Decide what build SDK you want to try to use. You might just choose
  the highest SDK version you have installed. Or, you can use the
  android:minSdkVersion and the -vNN resource set qualifiers to get
  clues as to what a good build SDK might be. If desired, create a
  project.properties file with a target=android-NNN line, where NNN is
  your chosen build SDK. Or, you can address this in Eclipse later on.
- Import the resulting project into Eclipse, and if needed adjust the
  build SDK (Project > Properties > Android). Also, you will need to
  attach to this library project any library projects it depends upon
  (e.g., mediarouter-v7 depends upon appcompat-v7).

Good Luck!

And Special thanks to [***commonsware***](https://commonsware.com/blog/) !!

Answer (score 0):

A great fix to that problem is that you copy the sdk\extras\android\support\design\libs\android-support-design.jar file to "libs" folder of your project